# ¿Por qué no funciona? ¿Es por el último if?

Tags: java

El programa debería ser capaz de imprimir en pantalla las palabras que tengan solo 1 tipo de vocal:

> pala, orco, ese, pepe.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    char caracter = ' ';
    char[] palabra = new char[20];
    int numLetras;

    System.out.print("Introduce la secuencia de caracteres: ");

    while (caracter == ' ') {

        caracter = (char) System.in.read();
    }

    while (caracter != '.') {
        numCaracteres = 0;
        boolean LetraA = false;
        boolean LetraE= false;
        boolean LetraI= false;
        boolean LetraO= false;
        boolean LetraU= false;

        while ((caracter != '.') && (caracter != ' ')) {

            palabra[numLetras] = caracter;
            numLetras++;

            if (caracter == 'a') {
                LetraA= true;
            }
            if (caracter == 'e') {
                LetraE= true;
            }
            if (caracter == 'i') {
                LetraI= true;
            }
            if (caracter == 'o') {
                LetraO= true;
            }
            if (caracter == 'u') {
                LetraU= true;
            }
            caracter = (char) System.in.read();
        }

        /*Posible fallo aqui*/

        if (((LetraA= true) && (LetraE= false) && (LetraI= false) && (LetraO= false) && (LetraU= false)) || ((LetraA= false) && (LetraE= true) && (vocalI = false) && (LetraO= false) && (LetraU= false)) || ((LetraA= false) && (LetraE= false) && (LetraI= true) && (LetraO= false) && (LetraU= false)) || ((LetraA= false) && (LetraE= false) && (LetraI= false) && (LetraO= true) && (LetraU= false)) || ((LetraA= false) && (LetraE= false) && (LetraI= false) && (LetraO= false) && (LetraU= true))) {

            System.out.print(" ");

            for (int indice = 0; indice < numLetras; indice++) {
                System.out.print(palabra[indice]);
            }
            System.out.println();
       }

        while (caracter == ' ') {
            caracter = (char) System.in.read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías un ejemplo de lo que introduces por pantalla? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: run:
 Introduce la secuencia de caracteres: hola como ese avion.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

No da ningun error, simplemente no imprime las palabras.

Comment: antes del if del posible fallo, verifica que guarda cada boolean...
LetraA, LetraE, LetraI, LetraO, LetraU.....

No le veo nada malo al último if, y puede que error sea antes..

Comment: Ya esta , el error que he tenido me lo ha identificado el usuario rn3w, igualmente muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: @Roggi En la parte del código que has mostrado hay más errores. Comprueba mi respuesta (a no ser de que los tengas inicializados más arriba).

Comment: Elimino mi respuesta ya que los demás errores que tienes en el código, tal y como me has comentado, en tu código real no los tienes y la respuesta de @rn3w es correcta. Un saludo! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba modificando asi:

```
if (((LetraA== true) && (LetraE== false) && (LetraI== false) && (LetraO== false) && (LetraU== false)) || ((LetraA== false) && (LetraE== true) && (vocalI == false) && (LetraO== false) && (LetraU== false)) || ((LetraA== false) && (LetraE== false) && (LetraI== true) && (LetraO== false) && (LetraU== false)) || ((LetraA== false) && (LetraE== false) && (LetraI== false) && (LetraO== true) && (LetraU== false)) || ((LetraA== false) && (LetraE== false) && (LetraI== false) && (LetraO== false) && (LetraU== true))) {

            System.out.print(" ");

            for (int indice = 0; indice < numLetras; indice++) {
                System.out.print(palabra[indice]);
            }
            System.out.println();
       }
```

creo que estas confundiendo el operador de asignacion(=) con el operador de igualdad(==)

nota1: creo que se te paso la mano con esta variable vocalI, al parecer no existe vocalI

Comment: Ese ha sido mi error, muchas gracias!